# How to prevent auto save when executing code in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run my code in Visual Studio, it auto saves my code -without prompting (!)- even though I have auto-save set to off. Is there a way to prevent this?

I've made sure auto-save is off in preferences. I haven't seen any setting that applies specifically to "on execute"

As an example of how this made me lose some hair, I opened a file that had some unknown characters (which opened just fine in Powershell ISE) and I didn't know until the code failed when I executed it. And since it auto-saved on execute, it wrote the bad characters to the file, corrupting it for all eternity. Not to mention, if I modify a few characters to test something, I don't want it to auto-save for me.

Comment: Are you using an extension to run the code?

Comment: Try going to settings > extensions > Run Code configuration. There's a setting in there called 'save file before run' that you can uncheck.

Comment: Thanks - It is Powershell, and there is no setting under the extensions section for "save file before you run"

Answer (score -1):

Search for `autosave` under `File-> Preferences - Settings` and turn it off

[image]

Comment: Thanks but as I noted in my desciption 'Ive made sure auto-save is off in preferences'